# Document based app shows 2 back chevrons on iPad

Tags: swiftui

I did a small sample application to show my problem. I used the multi-platform document app template that Xcode 14.0.1 offers, creating my own package file format for this.
I want to create a document based app running on macOS and on iPad.

When running on macOS, everything works as expected.

On the iPad, when opening the app, the file chooser opens.

[image]

On opening an existing or creating a new file, the screen looks like this:

[image]

The left chevron does nothing, while the right chevron shows the document chooser again.
What's the left, ever so slightly larger chevron on the left doing here and how can I get of it? Is this an error with the framework that should be reported to Apple?

PS don't get distracted by the name of this sample app–the real app will need some navigation and I first thought the 2nd chevron show up cause of this–in the sample I built for this post, there is no navigation though. So this 2nd chevron seems to be a "built in" issue...

For the sake of completeness, here's my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct so_DocumentAppWithNavigationShowsMultipleChevronsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: so_DocumentAppWithNavigationShowsMultipleChevronsDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
    }
}

import UniformTypeIdentifiers

extension UTType {
    static var appfroschFile: UTType {
        UTType(importedAs: "ch.appfros.so-DocumentAppWithNavigationShowsMultipleChevrons")
    }
}

struct so_DocumentAppWithNavigationShowsMultipleChevronsDocument: FileDocument {
    var document: Document

    init(document: Document = Document(text: "Hello, world!")) {
        self.document = document
    }

    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.appfroschFile] }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let fileWrappers = configuration.file.fileWrappers
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        guard let documentFileWrapper = fileWrappers["document"],
              let data = documentFileWrapper.regularFileContents,
              let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        document = try JSONDecoder().decode(Document.self, from: data)
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(document)
        let documentFileWrapper = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: data)
        
        let mainFileWrapper = FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [
            "document": documentFileWrapper
        ])
        return mainFileWrapper
    }
}

struct Document: Codable {
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: so_DocumentAppWithNavigationShowsMultipleChevronsDocument

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $document.document.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: The above mentioned behaviour persists in Xcode 14.1 Release Candidate 2 (14B47b) for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can see the same problem with the default Document based app when using Xcode 14.1 (14B47) running on the iPad simulator with iOS 16.1. So definitely a bug (and worth reporting to A as such).

At a guess, the second, non-functional back button is what would have been the back button for navigating in SideBar. And the logic to not display when working on a document is what has been broken.

Fortunately simple workaround for the bug is to explicitly specify toolbar's role using the `toolbarRole` modifier, e.g.

```
@main
struct so_DocumentAppWithNavigationShowsMultipleChevronsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: so_DocumentAppWithNavigationShowsMultipleChevronsDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
                .toolbarRole(.navigationStack) // <-- Specifying this gets rid of double chevron on iOS
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm the above mentioned workaround. 